# Query to produce data only within the asked hour range

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL:

I been trying to get this some snippet of query working. When you run it, it prompts you for an hour, and displays no records. I don’t want the query to have a static hour as it will need to be run 4 times a day.
So from the ‘&date’ input, I want it to show data for the past 24 hours. Is that possible?

```
dt_time = timestamp(6) field

select distinct to_char(dt_ time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24'), fault_description
from order
where to_char(dt_time,'hh24') <= '&date' -24
order by to_char(dt_ time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24');
```

Example, if you enter 10 (when query executed) it will show the data from 10(:00) through to 10(:00)next day

[Hope there is enough info for someone to answer, please]

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `between` and `interval`:

```
where dt_time between  
to_date(&date, 'ddmmyyyy hh24') and 
to_date(&date, 'ddmmyyyy hh24') + interval  '24' hour
```

You'll need to pass/parse the input date as a full date and not only the hour part, in order to prevent unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` in a CTE to get the hour as user input.

```
WITH t_hour( h ) AS
  ( SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(&d,'HOUR' ) h FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(dt_time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24'),
  fault_description
FROM ORDER
CROSS JOIN t_hour
WHERE dt_time BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) + h AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 + h
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: thanks for getting back but I am getting multiple number of rows with the same hour:   17/11/2017 11     Fault_45I4568_box

Comment: @sbirdi : what do you mean? May I know how you used my query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `SYSDATE` as you are fetching last one day data.
Also if you add or subtract number with a date column the offset will be number of days, not number of hours. So you need to use `&date/24`

Try this:

```
select distinct to_char(dt_time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24'), fault_description
from order
where dt_time - &date / 24 between TRUNC(sysdate-1) and TRUNC(sysdate)   
order by to_char(dt_ time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24');
```

Please comment.

Comment: Brilliant that has worked....Thanks mate, you made  my Friday a better day

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(SYSDATE,DT_TIME) * 24  < &DATE AND DT_TIME < SYSDATE
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back, but don't think DATEDIFF is an oracle command as failing with  ORA-00904 'DATEDIFF' : invalid identifier